# Проблема наложения слоёв

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть чёрный блок который наложен на красный блок, у чёрного блока есть зелёный блок который должен быть сзади красного блока. Как такое организовать без редактирования html кода?
https://jsfiddle.net/ooceokLd/1/

```css
.l {
  border: 1px black solid;
  z-index: 0;
}
.q1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.q2 {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150px;
  left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
}
p {
  z-index: -2;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  right: -35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="l">
<div class="q2"><p></p></div>
<div class="q1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.l {
  border: 1px black solid;
  z-index: 0;
}
.q1{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.q2 {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150px;
  left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
}
p {
  z-index: -2;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  right: -25px;
}
p:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="l">
<div class="q2"><p></p></div>
<div class="q1"></div>
</div>
```